# When I create a new instance of a class in python, it won't pass the right information through the constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, artificial-intelligence

This is a try to make a simple *AI* solution to solve the *peg solitaire*, using *Depth First Search* (recursive version).

My problem is in `potentialMovesDFS` function:

```
newNodes.append(Node(Node.non,problemBuf,None))
```

although `problemBuf` changes, the old value is passed.

I thing it has to do with pointers but I don't know how to solve this.

Any ideas?

```
Tree = []


class Node():
    non = 0

    def __init__(self,iD,dt,ch):
        self.iD = Node.non
        self.data = dt
        self.children = []
        Tree.append(self)
        Node.non = Node.non + 1

    def winCheck(self):
        counter = 0
        for j in range(y):
            counter += problem[j].count('1')
        return counter

    def addChildren(self,ch):
        self.children.append(ch)

    def getParent(self):
        return self.parent

    def printNode(self):
        print('\n')
        print("iD:",self.iD)
        print("Data:",self.data)
        print("Child:",self.children)
        print('\n')

    def printData(self):
        for j in range(y):
            for i in range(x):
                    print(problem[j][i],end='')
                    print("  ",end='')
            print('\n')

    #4 cases of movement
    def potentialMovesDFS(self,problem):
        newMoves = []
        newNodes = []
        problemBuf = problem[:]
        for j in range(y):
            for i in range(x):
                    if(problem[j][i]=='2'):
                        #print(problem[j][i+2]=='1',problem[j][i+1]=='1',i<=x-3)
                        #print("Space at:",j,i)
                        if(j>=2 and problem[j-2][i]=='1' and problem[j-1][i]=='1'):
                            #print("Move",j-2,i,"to",j,i,"and remove",j-1,i,'\n')
                            print('1')
                            buf = problemBuf[j][:i]+'1'+problemBuf[j][i+1:]
                            problemBuf[j] = buf
                            #aka problem[j][i] = '1'
                            buf = problemBuf[j-1][:i]+'2'+problemBuf[j-1][i+1:]
                            problemBuf[j-1] = buf
                            #aka problem[j-1][i] = '2'
                            buf = problemBuf[j-2][:i]+'2'+problemBuf[j-2][i+1:]
                            problemBuf[j-2] = buf
                            #aka problem[j-2][i] = '1'
                            newNodes.append(Node(Node.non,problemBuf,None))
                            newMoves.append(problemBuf)
                            problemBuf = problem[:]   

                        if(i<=x-3 and problem[j][i+2]=='1' and problem[j][i+1]=='1'):
                            #print("Move",j,i+2,"to",j,i,"and remove",j,i+1,'\n')
                            print('2')
                            buf = problemBuf[j][:i]+'1'+problemBuf[j][i+1:]
                            problemBuf[j] = buf
                            buf = problemBuf[j][:i+1]+'2'+problemBuf[j][i+2:]
                            problemBuf[j] = buf
                            buf = problemBuf[j][:i+2]+'2'+problemBuf[j][i+3:]
                            problemBuf[j] = buf
                            newNodes.append(Node(Node.non,problemBuf,None))

                            newMoves.append(problemBuf)
                            problemBuf = problem[:]

                        if(j<=y-3 and problem[j+2][i]=='1' and problem[j+1][i]=='1'):
                            #print("Move",j+2,i,"to",j,i,"and remove",j+1,i,'\n')
                            print('3')
                            buf = problemBuf[j][:i]+'1'+problemBuf[j][i+1:]
                            problemBuf[j] = buf
                            buf = problemBuf[j+1][:i]+'2'+problemBuf[j+1][i+1:]
                            problemBuf[j+1] = buf
                            buf = problemBuf[j+2][:i]+'2'+problemBuf[j+2][i+1:]
                            problemBuf[j+2] = buf
                            newNodes.append(Node(Node.non,problemBuf,None))

                            newMoves.append(problemBuf[:])
                            problemBuf = problem[:]  

                        if(i>=2 and problem[j][i-2]=='1' and problem[j][i-1]=='1'):
                            #print("Move",j,i-2,"to",j,i,"and remove",j,i-1,'\n')
                            print('4')
                            buf = problemBuf[j][:i]+'1'+problemBuf[j][i+1:]
                            problemBuf[j] = buf
                            buf = problemBuf[j][:i-1]+'2'+problemBuf[j][i:]
                            problemBuf[j] = buf
                            buf = problemBuf[j][:i-2]+'2'+problemBuf[j][i-1:]
                            problemBuf[j] = buf
                            newNodes.append(Node(Node.non,problemBuf,None))

                            newMoves.append(problemBuf)
                            problemBuf = problem[:]

        return newNodes

#read file
inputFile = open("m.txt","r")
problem = inputFile.readlines()
x,y = problem[0].split(' ')
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
problem = problem[1:y+1]
for i in range(y):
    problem[i] = problem[i].replace(' ','')
    problem[i] = problem[i].replace('\n','')

'''
def dfs_recursive(graph, vertex, path=[]):
    path += [vertex]
    for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
        if neighbor not in path:
            path = dfs_recursive(graph, neighbor, path)
    return path
adjacency_matrix = {1: [2, 3], 2: [4, 5],
                    3: [5], 4: [6], 5: [6],
                    6: [7], 7: []}
print(dfs_recursive(adjacency_matrix, 1))'''

def dfs_recursive(thisNode, path=[]):
    path.append(thisNode)

    #leipei h potential
    for child in thisNode.potentialMovesDFS(thisNode.data):
        if child not in path:
            path = dfs_recursive(child, path)

    return path



#set tree root
root = Node(Node.non,problem,None)
print(root.printData())


for i in dfs_recursive(root):
    print(i.printData())
```

Comment: Your `__init__` method appears to ignore the `iD` parameter.

Comment: Same as with `ch`. Confusing. Anyway, in `potentialMovesDFS` you make a copy of your `problem[:]` list. Might help if you do the same in the constructor of `Node` for `dt`. I didn't go through all the code, but maybe there's an interaction here between two references to the same (mutable) list.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  This code is not at all minimal.